# I have a discord.js API error, code: 10062

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a simple rules embed that only I can use, I use the command but the error below pops up

I dont know why this error is occurring

My code:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, ApplicationCommandType, EmbedBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
      .setName("rules")
      .setDescription("rules")
      .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageServer),

      async execute(interaction) {
        if(interaction.user.id === '1078011590927990896'){
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Rules')
        .addFields(
        { name: '**Rule 1**', value: '**No spamming**\nSpamming is against Discord\'s TOS, so please refrain from spamming especially when people are in a conversation.' },
        { name: '**Rule 2**', value: '**No slurs**\nWords like fu## and sh## are accepted but not to be spammed, but any member who sends words like the n-word or any other words like that will be timed out'},
        { name: '**Rule 3', value: '**No advertising**\nThere is a specific advertising channel so there is no need, you may DM advertise if the member accepts it.'}
        )
        .setColor('#22DD22')
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] })
    } 
   }
}
```

My error:

```js
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, "code" in data ? data.code : data.error, status, method, url, requestData);
            ^

DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction
    at handleErrors (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async BurstHandler.runRequest (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:736:23)
    at async REST.request (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1387:22)
    at async ChatInputCommandInteraction.deferReply (C:\Users\joebo\OneDrive\Desktop\WAIT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\InteractionResponses.js:69:5) {
  requestBody: { files: undefined, json: { type: 5, data: { flags: undefined } } },
  rawError: { message: 'Unknown interaction', code: 10062 },
  code: 10062,
  status: 404,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/interactions/1106990055844753588/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTEwNjk5MDA1NTg0NDc1MzU4ODplVndqMG54cjFIbXU5TE1SbWgzckV4NGlWUTV2V0NkZWFHODRNOWxsVWxGRzl6R2hNNzc2bGZ6Zkk2TDRidTE5MjE1Q2tTbjN3a1Y5c1V1eGp3NDh6blBmU3JiYmN5WHVDclRFc0U5anppejA3anNkUXFVSFpwRjZMQ0RCS0w1bg/callback'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply forgot to ask for interaction in the exported module.
I'm still beginning in discord js but I would have made my export as `module.exports => (interaction) {my code using interaction.# here}`. I think that should resolve the problem if your index.js and the other files are made correctly. I'm not sure of how to add options to a `module.exports = {}` way of doing so I only gave the one I'm familiar with.